# how to use a instance variable from one Class in other class?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes Student Event and Booking. In the Student class there are methods 'register' and 'login'. I want to use the 'universityID' from Student class(used for registration/login) in the Event Class to add/list the events of the given student to/from the database, or to use that 'universityID' in the Booking Class to make a booking for the event and add it in the database with that given 'universityID'

these are the classes:

```
public class Student
{
  private DB db=new DB();
    //creating a private instance variables
  private String universityID;
  private String password;
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String email;

 //the Studentconstructor with five formal parameters
 public Student(String initUniId, String initPass, String inintFN, String initLN, String initEmail){
  initUniId=universityID;  
  initPass=password;
  inintFN=firstname;
  initLN=lastname;
  initEmail=email;

 }

 /*creating a method 'setUniversityID' with formal parameter of type String
  * that doesn't return a value as it has the 'void' keyword 
  */
    public void setUniversityID(String newUniversityID){
      universityID=newUniversityID;//assigning the parameter value to the instance variable 'universityID'
    }

    /*creating a method 'setPassword' with formal parameter of type String
     * that doesn't return a value as it has the 'void' keyword 
     */
    public void setPassword(String newPassword){
      password=newPassword;//assigning the parameter value to the instance variable 'password'
    }

    /*creating a method 'setFirstname' with formal parameter of type String
     * that doesn't return a value as it has the 'void' keyword 
     */
       public void setFirstname(String newFirstname){
       firstname=newFirstname;//assigning the parameter value to the instance variable 'firstname'
    }

    /*creating a method 'setLastname' with formal parameter of type String
     * that doesn't return a value as it has the 'void' keyword 
     */
     public void setLastname(String newLastname){
       lastname=newLastname;//assigning the parameter value to the instance variable 'lastname'
    }

    /*creating a method 'setEmail' with formal parameter of type String
     * that doesn't return a value as it has the 'void' keyword 
     */
           public void setEmail(String newEmail){
       email=newEmail;//assigning the parameter value to the instance variable 'email'
     }

    /*creating a method 'getUniversityID' 
     * to return a String value 
     */
       public String getUniversityID(){
      return universityID;//returning the value of instance variable 'universityID'
    }

    /*creating a method 'getPassword' 
     * to return a String value 
     */
     public String getPassword(){
      return password;//returning the value of instance variable 'password'
    }

    /*creating a method 'getFirstname' 
     * to return a String value 
     */
      public String getFirstname(){
      return firstname;//returning the value of instance variable 'firstname'
    }

    /*creating a method 'getLastname' 
     * to return a String value 
     */
    public String getLastname(){
      return lastname;//returning the value of instance variable 'lastname'
    }

    /*creating a method 'getEmail' 
     * to return a String value 
     */
    public String getEmail(){
      return email;//returning the value of instance variable 'email'
    }
public void register() {

     try{
      db.prst=db.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student (UniversityID,FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);"); 

      db.prst.setString(1,getUniversityID());
      db.prst.setString(2,getFirstname());
      db.prst.setString(3,getLastname());
      db.prst.setString(4,getEmail());
      db.prst.setString(5,getPassword());

      db.prst.executeUpdate();

      System.out.println("Thank you for the registration");
      System.out.println("Now you can sign in into your account");


    }catch(SQLException err){
        err.printStackTrace(System.err);
             System.out.println(err.getMessage()); 
}



  public class Event 
    {
      //creating an object of the class <DB> and naming it with the variable <db>
      private DB db=new DB();
      //defining the instance variables 
      private String title;
      private String type;
      private String addressOrURL;
      private String startDate;
      private String endDate;
      private String description;
      private String placeLimit;
      private String bookingRequired;

        public Event(String initTitle, String initType, String initAddressOrURL,String initStartDate, String initEndDate, String initDescription, String initPlaceLimit, String initBookingRequired){
           initTitle=title;
           initType=type;
           initAddressOrURL=addressOrURL;
           initStartDate=startDate;
           initEndDate=endDate;
           initDescription=description;
           initPlaceLimit=placeLimit;
           initBookingRequired=bookingRequired;
         }

          public void setTitle(String newTitle){
             title=newTitle;
             }

        public void setType(String newType){
             type=newType;
            }

             public void setAddressOrURL(String newAddressOrURL){
             addressOrURL=newAddressOrURL;
            }

              public void setStartDate(String newStartDate){
              startDate=newStartDate;
             }

            public void setEndDate(String newEndDate){
             endDate=newEndDate;
            }

            public void setDescription(String newDescription){
             description=newDescription;
            }

         public void setPlaceLimit(String newPlaceLimit){
             placeLimit=newPlaceLimit;
            }

       public void setBookingRequired(String newBookingRequired){
             bookingRequired=newBookingRequired;
            }

            public void addEvent(){
                          try{
        db.prst=db.conn.prepareStatement("select StudentID from student where role=\"Organiser\" and UniversityID=?");
    **I want to use the universityID here to check if the student has the role =organiser in database **
                  db.prst.setString(1,????);
                 db.rs=db.prst.executeQuery();
if(db.rs.next()){
try{
insert sql statement}
    }else{
sysout("don't have rights");}
                    }catch(SQLException err)
                   {
                       err.printStackTrace(System.err);
                       System.out.println(err.getMessage()); 
                   }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Student` instance to the method(s) that need the universityID. Something like,

```
public void register(Student s) {
    String universityID = s.getUniversityID();
    // ...
```

Comment: it's working, but when Im trying to call the register method I have a error <method register in class Student cannot be applied to given types;>